# should i call startforeground(id, notification) if i recreate notification? android above Oreo, api28

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

## Hi !!

I am wondering if I should call startForeground(id, notification) whenever I create Notification Object.
or is it okay calling NotificationManger.notify(id, notification) ?

Here is a sample i brought

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Start Foreground Intent ");
            Notification notification = getNotification();
            startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,
                    notification);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Previous");     <---------------------------------1
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Play");         <---------------------------------2
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Next");         <---------------------------------3
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(
                Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Stop Foreground Intent");
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private Notification getNotification() {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    notificationIntent, 0);

            Intent previousIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
            previousIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);
            PendingIntent ppreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                    previousIntent, 0);

            Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
            playIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION);
            PendingIntent pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                    playIntent, 0);

            Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
            nextIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION);
            PendingIntent pnextIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                    nextIntent, 0);

            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.truiton_short);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Truiton Music Player")
                    .setTicker("Truiton Music Player")
                    .setContentText("My Music")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(
                            Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous,
                            "Previous", ppreviousIntent)
                    .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play, "Play",
                            pplayIntent)
                    .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "Next",
                            pnextIntent).build();

            return notification;
    }
```

At #1, #2, and #3, the notification view have to change playstate_icon, bitmap, title, or etc..
so I have to call `getNotification()`

## ***QUESTION!!***

**Should I call**

```
  startForeground(id, notification);
```

or

```
  NotificationManager.notifiy(id, notification);
```

**at #1, #2, and #3??? (or every recreated notification view)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `notify()`. There is no need to call `startForeground()` if your service is already a foreground service.

You can continue to update the notification as much as you want; just continue using the same notification ID you passed when you first called `startForeground()`. The system will understand that the new notification is associated with the foreground service.

Answer (score 0):

for api 31 and up use just   NotificationManager.notifiy(id, notification); remove   startForeground(id, notification);  (not allowed) also replace .startForegroundService (not allowed) by .startService

also disable activity on click for builder it will cause bug on api 31 and up

```
>> //intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
builder.setContentTitle(contentTitle)  ...

>> //   .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

....

i don use  androidx  // implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"

even if i use :

compileSdkVersion 31

targetSdkVersion 31

the fast way to get apk approved on google play without dealing with androidx